# AJAX request within promise is executed even after guard clause

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've ran into small puzzling issue: when I have a guard clause before my `$.ajax(...)` statement in a promise object, the AJAX request is still dispatched if the guard clause is activated:

```
function conditionalRequest(label, value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!value)
          reject(`${label}: Nothing is done`);

        // Still dispatched even if `value` is falsy
        $.ajax(...)
    });
}
```

However, placing a return statement in the guard clause will stop the downstream AJAX from being executed:

```
function conditionalRequest(label, value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!value) {
          reject(`${label}: Nothing is done`);
          return; // This fixes the issue
        }

        // Now when `value` is falsy, the guard clause ends :) 
        $.ajax(...)
    });
}
```

I might have missed something important here, because I simply assume that calling `resolve()` or `reject()` will imply a `return` within a promise. Here is the code above, but slightly expanded to demonstrate the issue better with logging to console enabled:

```js
function conditionalRequest(label, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!value) {
      console.log(`${label}: Value is falsy, guard statement activated`);
      reject(`${label}: Nothing is done`);
      return;
    }
    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
      type: 'GET',
      beforeSend: () => {
        console.log(`Sending request: ${label}`);
      }
    }).done(data => {
      console.log(`${label}: Data received`);
      resolve(data);
    }).fail(() => {
      reject(`${label}: Error with endpoint`);
    });
  });
};

var asyncRequest1 = conditionalRequest('Request #1', true);
var asyncRequest2 = conditionalRequest('Request #2', false);

asyncRequest1.then(successPayload => {
  console.log(successPayload);
}, failurePayload => {
  console.log(failurePayload);
});
asyncRequest2.then(successPayload => {
  console.log(successPayload);
}, failurePayload => {
  console.log(failurePayload);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: resolve / reject just sets the value passed to the then() callbacks, it isnt an implied return.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you, that makes a lot of sense :) if you add your comment as an answer I'll be more than happy to accept it. Cheers!